# How to embedd array of struct in another struct and save it in database using GORM framework in golang

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

```golang
type DLInformation struct {
    Base64EncodedImage string `json:"base64_encoded_image"`
    LicenseNo          string `json:"license_no" gorm:"type:varchar(25)"`
    LicenseNumber      string `json:"license_number" gorm:"primaryKey;type:varchar(25)"`
    Name               string `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(30);not null"`
    FatherName         string `json:"father_name" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    DOB                string `json:"dob" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    BloodGroup         string `json:"blood_group" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
    Gender             string `json:"gender" gorm:"type:varchar(10)"`
    Status             string `json:"status" gorm:"type:varchar(40)"`
    RTO                string `json:"rto" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    PresentAddress     string `json:"present_address" gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
    State              string `json:"state" gorm:"type:varchar(30)"`
    //Licenses           []License `json:"licenses" gorm:"references:LicenseID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
    Licenses []License `json:"licenses" gorm:"embedded"`
    Vehicles []Vehicle `json:"vehicles" gorm:"embedded"`
    //Vehicles           []Vehicle `json:"vehicles" gorm:"references:VehicleID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
}


type License struct {
    LicenseType string `json:"license_type"`
    IssueDate   string `json:"issue_date"`
    ExpiryDate  string `json:"expiry_date"`
    LicenseID   uint64 `gorm:"autoIncrement;primaryKey"`
}

type Vehicle struct {
    VehicleClassKey   string `json:"vehicle_class_key"`
    VehicleClassValue string `json:"vehicle_class_value"`
    VehicleID         uint64 `gorm:"autoIncrement;primaryKey"`
}
```

I am new to GORM and I want to save object of type **DLInformation** in database but due to array of type **License** and **Vehicle** present inside **DLInformation** object I am unable to save it in Database.

**Getting error like this:-**
invalid field found for struct dl-scraping/models.DLInformation's field Licenses: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

**When I defined foreign key like this:-**

```
Licenses []License `json:"licenses" gorm:"foreignKey:LicenseID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`

Vehicles []Vehicle `json:"vehicles" gorm:"foreignKey:VehicleID;constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE"`
```

**then getting error:-** VehicleID and LicenseID doesn't have default value

Comment: Have you read this ? https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values

Comment: Yes, I use default value but this was not worked.

Comment: @SAGARDOBARIYA which db you are working with?

Comment: @Chandan I am working with MySql

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `Scan` and `Value` methods for each of your custom struct, so gorm can know how it has to store it and retrieve it from the database.